# IsAdminUser returns incorrect value

Tags: c, windows, perl, winapi

I'm using `Win32::IsAdminUser()` function  (Can't paste code because to make it runnable I would have to paste whole code). It returns 0, I was curious why because the user with which this is run is member of Administrators group, so I created a little test function (c++) and run it right before running `IsAdminUser` Here is the code:

```
int davai()
{
FILE * fp;

fp = fopen ("C:\\tmp\\davai.txt", "a");
fprintf(fp, "shevedi davai");
fflush(fp);

HANDLE token = NULL;
HANDLE dupToken = NULL;

if(!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &token))
{
  fprintf(fp, "davai: OpenProcessToken cheijva. %d\n", (int)GetLastError());
  fflush(fp);
}

if (DuplicateTokenEx(token, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityDelegation,
                          TokenPrimary, &dupToken) == 0)
{
  fprintf(fp, "davai: OpenProcessToken DuplicateTokenEx. %d\n", (int)GetLastError());
  fflush(fp);
}

PTOKEN_GROUPS pPrivilegesToken = NULL;
DWORD cbSize = 0;

GetTokenInformation(dupToken, TokenGroups, NULL, 0, &cbSize);

pPrivilegesToken = (PTOKEN_GROUPS) LocalAlloc(LPTR, cbSize);

if (GetTokenInformation(dupToken, TokenGroups, 
                             pPrivilegesToken, cbSize, &cbSize) == FALSE)
{
  fprintf(fp, "davai: GetTokenInformation cheijva. %d\n", (int)GetLastError());
  fflush(fp);
}

char * gio;

for (ULONG i = 0; i < pPrivilegesToken->GroupCount; i++)
{
  if (ConvertSidToStringSid(pPrivilegesToken->Groups[i].Sid, &gio) == 0)
  {
    fprintf(fp, "davai: ConvertSidToStringSid cheijva. %d\n", (int)GetLastError());
    fflush(fp);
  }
 
  fprintf(fp, "Value: %s\n",gio);
  fflush(fp);
}

LocalFree (gio);

return 1;
}
```

which just opens current processes token, and lists all the groups that user is involved in. Here is the ouput I get:

```
shevedi davaiValue: S-1-5-21-1018819917-2920201817-244685803-513
Value: S-1-1-0
Value: S-1-5-21-1018819917-2920201817-244685803-1000
Value: S-1-5-32-544
Value: S-1-5-32-545
Value: S-1-5-4
Value: S-1-2-1
Value: S-1-5-11
Value: S-1-5-15
Value: S-1-5-5-0-179095
Value: S-1-2-0
Value: S-1-5-64-10
Value: S-1-16-12288
```

which is strange because `S-1-5-32-544` represent `Administrators` group. I searched to find if someones has similar problem, but could not find anything (I'm running windows 7). Maybe you can help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you ignore attributes on group . you not check for `SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY`

Comment: print not only *Sid* but *Attributes* from `SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES` - may be you understand after this that user not have *S-1-5-32-544* really

Comment: ok I'll check in a minute

Comment: and for what you call`DuplicateTokenEx` ?! query direct from original token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which is strange because *S-1-5-32-544* represent Administrators
>   group.

really `Win32::IsAdminUser()` internally call [CheckTokenMembership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376389(v=vs.85).aspx) function with *SidToCheck* == *S-1-5-32-544* and return you *IsMember* as result. but

> If the SID is present and has the **SE_GROUP_ENABLED** attribute,
>   IsMember returns TRUE; otherwise, it returns FALSE.

and

> Even if a SID is present in the token, the system may not use the SID
>   in an access check. The SID may be disabled or have the
>   **SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY** attribute.

really if you user is member of admin group (*S-1-5-32-544*) but run without elevation (under *UAC*) *S-1-5-32-544* is present in token but with **SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY** attribute only

in contrast elevated admins have this *SID* with **SE_GROUP_ENABLED** attribute

so i guess you run as not elevated admin. `Win32::IsAdminUser()` and must return false in this case

Comment: You save me again :). I checked and attribute is `SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY`. thank you very much for this kind of explanation :)

Comment: One more question please, if the user (which is running this code) is logged in as interactive he has value of 15(which is decimal representation) and when user is logged in as batch the following situation  that is in question. Is this because the user with interactive logon is member of INTERACTIVE group?

Comment: @Rasty - if admin user log as batch he will be have *S-1-5-32-544* with *SE_GROUP_ENABLED* (+several attr) in contrast with interactive logon (will be *SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY*). this related to admins sid. `INTERACTIVE` and `BATCH` different groups

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding but as I unerstand INTERACTIVE logon produces restricted token right?

Comment: @Rasty - say different logon types can produce different token for same account. INTERACTIVE not always restrict. say not restrict built-in admin. not restrict if UAC is off

Comment: and for any other situation it would be restricted? Is there any documentation that would verify that?

Comment: @Rasty - don't know are / where this difference interactive vs batch documented (i know this by experience only), most general document [How Access Tokens Work](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783557(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

As documented in [Win32](http://p3rl.org/Win32#Win3236):

> On Windows Vista it will only return non-zero if the process is actually running with elevated privileges.

I'd understand "Vista" as "Vista and newer".

Comment: Yes but how can I prove that It really means that? Is there any answer besides testing it on every windows?

Comment: That is what it means.